# implement subdirectory in makefile

Tags: c, makefile

```
WARNFLAGS = -W -Wall -Werror
OPTFLAGS = -O3
CFLAGS += $(WARNFLAGS) $(OPTFLAGS)
CC = gcc
DOBJS = /Desktop/Sysprog/Uebungsblatt6/a4/awesome2/awesome.h /Desktop/Sysprog/Uebungsblatt6/a4/awesome3/awesome.h
#MODULES = awesome2 awesome3
$(OBJS): /Desktop/Sysprog/Uebungsblatt6/a4/awesome2/awesome.h /Desktop/Sysprog/Uebungsblatt6/a4/awesome3/awesome.h


awesome: 
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) awesome.c -o $@


clean:
rm -f *~ *.o awesome
```

I have tried everything, but don´t know how to include a headerfile from a subdirectory, into makefile.

My `awesome.c` is in directory `a4`, `awesome.h` is in directory `awesome2` and `awesome3`, and I want to compile `awesome.c`, but if I compile it does do not find `awesome.h`. How can I make it work.

Comment: `#include "awesome2/awesome.h"`?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Paste the error message into the question.

Comment: `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -Iawesome2 ...`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the .h file in your .c file.

There are two forms of the include directive you can put in your C source file:

```
#include "path/filename.h"
```

This version, with the file to include between quotes, includes a file relative to the directory of the .c file. You could of course put an absolute path there, but that is not recommended as you have to adapt it whenever you move the code/.h-file to another machine or place.

```
#include <path/filename.h>
```

With the file to include between < and >, the file will be searched relative to an include path you provide the compiler. In your case:

```
INC= /Desktop/Sysprog/Uebungsblatt6/a4/

$(CC) $(CFLAGS) awesome.c -o -I$(INC) $@
```

The -I switch is used by many compilers to provide it with a standard include path. It may be different for your compiler (and a guru may provide some adjustment, as my Make is rusty).

Comment: I'm not sure whether I'm a guru, but `make` variables are set using `=`, not `:`.  (Or GNU `make` has `:=`, too, but that has slightly different semantics.)

Comment: Since the OP says "awesome.h is in directory awesome2 ***and*** awesome3", I'm inclined to guess that they want to select between those.  In that case, putting the path into the C source is probably not the way to go.  That's in any case unnecessary if one intends to use a `-I` compiler option.